# What defines a Muslim?

Tags: reference-request

I have found and lost a source that states that a Muslim (as distinguished to a Believer) is someone who will not, as I remember, "attack a fellow human by hand or by mouth".

To my memory the source was somewhere in the Quran, or at least in the sayings of Muhammad.

Please give me a reference if this is true or not.

Comment: But please note that this is not the *definition* of a Muslim and is also not what *distinguishes* a Muslim from a Mumin. Rather it is one characteristic of a true Muslim.

Comment: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are refering to [Abu Hurairah Hadith](https://sunnah.com/nasai:4995), "The Muslim is the one from whose tongue and hand the people are safe".

Comment: So, being a Muslim is more than being a Believer?